# ¿Por qué no funciona este buscador AJAX con acf custom field? Wordpress ACF

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[image: subcampo_idioma]

Tengo el anterior Advance Custom Field de sub categoria con el Nombre de "idioma"

y quiero que muestre la distintas profesiones, pero con el custom field sub categoria de idioma, es decir que busque inglés y me salgan todas las profesiones relacionadas con el inglés, pero no encuentro el problema...

```
<?php
echo '
    <form class="form form--search" action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="custom_field" value="idioma" />
                <input type="search" name="s" class="search__input" placeholder="Search for a name" />
                <button type="submit" class="button button--submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
';
require_once("../wp-load.php");
switch_to_blog(5);
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'profesiones' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_key'               => 'nombre_profesion',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
                'relation'  => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => $_POST['custom_field'],
                    'value'   =>  $query->query_vars['s'],
                    'compare' => '=',
                )
            )
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre de la profesion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<tr>
                <td><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_field('plural').'</a></td>
            </tr>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
endif;
wp_reset_query();
restore_current_blog();
?>
```

No estoy seguro de que esto sea así pero por lo que he visto por diferentes guías debería de ser así

Answer (score 0):

Ya tengo una solución al primer problema,

```
array(
                    'key'     => $_POST['custom_field'],
                    'value'   =>  $query->query_vars['s'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
```

pero no se como acceder a la subcategoria idioma